# Read an XML file in R and create a dataframe when nodes have different lengths and content

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to create a dataframe object from an XML file. Task seemed simple but after many attempts I cannot extract exactly what I want.

Original data comes from here:
https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/repertoire-national-des-certifications-professionnelles-et-repertoire-specifique/#resource-071a7029-f237-40b1-81ca-e3c1d78282b7

Basically, the document has more than 17K nodes with the same name which is "FICHES". One of those "sub-nodes" is "BLOCS_COMPETENCES". That "sub-node" has another one called "BLOC_COMPETENCES" (the difference is the S in BLOC) and this one has 2 nodes in which I am interested: CODE and LIBELLE.

However, not all "FICHES" have the same attributes and/or children nodes. Moreover, some of them have 1 "BLOC_COMPETENCES" with 1, 2, 3 or no elements at all.

Following [this document](https://rpubs.com/Howetowork/499292) (among other posts) I tried extracting the root node and accessing the elements with xpath:

```
# Import the file after zip extraction
RNCP_aout2020 <- xmlParse("U:/RNCP_2020/Fiches-rncp-2020-08-03/export_fiches_RNCP_2020-08-03.xml", encoding = "UTF-8")

# Finding root node
rootNode <- xmlRoot(RNCP_aout2020)

BLOCS_COMPETENCES <- as.data.frame(xpathSApply(rootNode, '/FICHES/FICHE/BLOCS_COMPETENCES/BLOC_COMPETENCES/CODE', xmlValue))
```

This works for extracting all nodes and attributes that are present. For example, the following line works when extracting the ID of each "FICHES":

```
# Extract ID
NUMERO_FICHE <- as.data.frame(xpathSApply(rootNode, '/FICHES/FICHE/NUMERO_FICHE', xmlValue))
```

But when I try with this for "BLOC_COMPETENCES", the length is different which makes it impossible to merge with the other columns.

I can provide all the code that I tried but not a reprex with the CSS format (for now) because I don't know how to subset the big file.

Any help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable number of "BLOC_COMPETENCES" does complicate the problem.  In the script below, parsed out all of the fiche nodes then loop through each node to retrieve the desired codes and libelles. Also needed to check for zero length codes and libelles.  Since the list of fiche is very long, the lapply statement will take awhile to complete.

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

#read the document
page <- read_xml("export_fiches_RNCP_2020-08-03.xml")

#read all fiches nodes
fiches <- xml_find_all(page, "//FICHE")

#parse each fiches
dfs <-lapply(fiches, function(node){
   id <- node %>% xml_find_first(".//ID_FICHE")  %>% xml_text()
   codes <-  node %>% xml_find_all(".//BLOC_COMPETENCES/CODE") %>% xml_text()
   libelles <- node %>% xml_find_all(".//BLOC_COMPETENCES/LIBELLE")%>% xml_text()
   #correct for codes which don't exist
   if (length(codes) <1 ) {codes = NA}
   if (length(libelles) <1 ) {libelles = NA}

   df<- data.frame(id, codes, libelles, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
})

#merge all of the data frames
answer <- bind_rows(dfs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! If you don't mind may I ask how much time did this took in your machine ? I tried even with parallel code (mclapply) but the task is just not being performed (waited more than 30mn).

Comment: Some news over here. Leave it about an hour and performed the task. Works perfect! I mark this as the final answer because it adapts more to the experience I have with R than the other one.

Comment: I was afraid you were going to ask that question.  It took about 20 minutes on my 3.2 GHz Core i5.  I don't think each iteration in the loops takes that long it is just a the large number of iterations, thus running it in parallel may not be a real time saver.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/) to transform your original XML to extract needed nodes. Then, use the convenience handler, `xmlToDataFrame`, avoiding `for` or `apply` family loops or `if` logic.

Being an independent, portable industry language, there are many ways to run XSLT 1.0 including [processors](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) like [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html), via other languages (Java, Python, PHP) or with R package `xslt`.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file used below)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- EXTRACT ONLY FICHE NODES -->
    <xsl:template match="/FICHES">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="FICHE"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- WITHIN EACH FICHE NODE, EXTRACT ONLY ITS DESCENDANT, BLOC_COMPETENCES NODES-->
    <xsl:template match="FICHE">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::BLOC_COMPETENCES"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- WITHIN EACH BLOC_COMPETENCE, DO TWO THINGS:            -->
    <!--      1. RETRIEVE UPPER LEVEL ANCESTOR NODE, ID_FICHE   -->
    <!--      2. RETRIEVE CODE AND LIBELLE CHILD NODES          -->
    <xsl:template match="BLOC_COMPETENCES">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::FICHE/ID_FICHE"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="CODE | LIBELLE"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Approach 1** *(using above XSLT in file named style.xsl)*

**R** + **`xsltproc`**

```
library(XML)

setwd("...")
system("xsltproc -o transformed.xml style.xsl export_fiches_RNCP_2020-08-03.xml")

doc <- xmlParse("transformed.xml")
doc
# <FICHES>
#   <BLOC_COMPETENCES>
#     <ID_FICHE>3614</ID_FICHE>
#     <CODE>RNCP13004BC01</CODE>
#     <LIBELLE>Du dérushage au montage</LIBELLE>
#   </BLOC_COMPETENCES>
#   <BLOC_COMPETENCES>
#     <ID_FICHE>3614</ID_FICHE>
#     <CODE>RNCP13004BC02</CODE>
#     <LIBELLE>Analyser un projet cinématographique</LIBELLE>
#   </BLOC_COMPETENCES>
#   <BLOC_COMPETENCES>
#     <ID_FICHE>3614</ID_FICHE>
#     <CODE>RNCP13004BC03</CODE>
#     <LIBELLE>Tourner sur fond d'incrustation </LIBELLE>
#   </BLOC_COMPETENCES>
#   <BLOC_COMPETENCES>
#   ...

df <- xmlToDataFrame(doc)
```

**Approach 2** *(using above XSLT in file named style.xsl)*

**R** + **`xslt`**

```
library(xml2)
library(xslt)
library(XML)

# PARSE XML AND XSLT
doc <- read_xml('export_fiches_RNCP_2020-08-03.xml')
style <- read_xml('style.xsl', package = "xslt")

# TRANSFORM NESTED INPUT INTO FLATTER OUTPUT
new_xml <- as.character(xslt::xml_xslt(doc, style))

# PARSE FLATTER XML
flat_xml <- XML::xmlParse(new_xml, asText=TRUE)

# BUILD DATA FRAME
df <- xmlToDataFrame(doc)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this complete answer ! However, I must admit I am not that familiar with what you are talking about in the first part of your answer. Is there any tutorial for beginners (or even better a certified online course) you might recommend ? I am also curious about how yo got a sample or preview in JSS format. I tried the code you wrote but I get the following error: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘xmlToDataFrame’ for signature ‘"xml_document", "missing", "missing", "missing", "missing"’.

Comment: I forgot to add the important instruction: *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*. See edit. No special course is needed. You may have heard of SQL, an external special-purpose declarative language that R can run to retrieve data from relational databases. Well, XSLT is also an external, special-purpose declarative language that R can run to transform (like flattening) XML files, using a special XML file to run its code. I show two ways to do this in R: with an external processor available on Unix machines (Mac/Linux) and with a package. Note: no loop is needed and does not take an hour!

Comment: I tried your alternative again because the other solution needs a huge amount of time but I don't really get it to work. Thank you in any case. I hope it helps somebody else.

Comment: You were not able to install `xslt` package (sister to `xml2`)? What was the error? Your post indicates you have `XML` and accepted answer you would have `xml2`.

Comment: I got xslt package working. I think it was related to an update issue. Anyway, I do have heard of SQL, I  see what a relational database is and I understand I don't need loops to access information. What I don't get is the first chunk of your answer (the one starting with <xsl:stylesheet) which I think is the most important part. What are all those parameters ? How do you know what to put in it ? How do you know where to write <xsl:template match="/FICHES"> instead of (for example) </xsl:copy>. The chunk where you create the xsl file if you want. In case I need to do it with other params.

Comment: The first chunk is a separate coding or scripting file (like SQL's `.sql`, Java's `.java`, Python's `.py`, or even like R's `.R` script). Actually, it is a special XML file that sends instructions to an XSLT engine. To teach the recursive template style of XSLT is beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question. However, I add comments into first chunk to show what each template does. Few don't like or understand it, but XSLT is awesome to me!

Comment: Allright it is much more clear right now. At first I thought it was a package or some easy workaround, then I got it was literally another language. Well I totally agree with you in the sense that it looks amazing by giving full handling on xml files. However giving the short time I had to manage the project I wasn't particularly looking to learn another language. BUT it goes directly to my to do list. I already tried some twiking with the data I am handling but gotta read the documentation and go all in with it. Thank you very much for your answers and your time!